# NoReverseMatch at /blog/create/

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error NoReverseMatch at /blog/create/, can anyone help me? Thank you.

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='account_login')
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            new_post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = request.user
            new_post.slug = slugify(new_post.title)
            new_post.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Post creates successfully')
            # redirect to new created item detail view
            return redirect(new_post.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        post_form = CreatePostForm()
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post_form': post_form})

def post_detail(request, id, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'section': 'blogs',
                                                        'post': post})
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES =   (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),    
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogs:post_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

urls.py for the app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create_post, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',
                           namespace='blogs',
                           app_name='blog')),
]
```

when i try to create a new post i get that error. I want to display the post thats created. Here is my form for creating the new post.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action=".">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ post_form.media }}
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                {% render_field post_form.title class="form-control" placeholder="Blog title" %}
                                {% render_field post_form.status class="form-control" %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px; height: 800px; width: 800px;">
                           {{ post_form.body }}
                        </div>  
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" style="min-width: 300px">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% if redirect_field_value %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                        {% endif %}
                     </fieldset>
                </form>
```

And I would like if you could explain me what was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when you post about an error, please give the full error message.

In this case the error is caused by the `get_absolute_url` method of your model. It's trying to reverse a url called "post_detail" passing  id and slug arguments. But as you can see from the urls.py, there isn't such a url: there's one called "detail" that takes those arguments, or one called "post_detail" that takes no arguments and strangely points to your create view.

Comment: After two years of on and off django use, it turned out to be this comment that finally made its ecosystem click for me. Cheers.